# When is it permissible to collect charity during prayer?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tzedakah-charity

In my shul someone usually brings around the pushka (charity box) during the chazzan's repetition of shmoneh esrei. I have also heard that it is appropriate to give tzedaka during [v'yivarech Dovid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_prayer#Related_customs). However there are people who come into shul to collect at all times of davening (known as meshulachim). Is it permissible for them to collect charity at any time during davening?

---

Note that a very similar question was asked [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/giving-tzedakah-during-birchos-krias-shema) but from what I can see seems to only be asking about **giving** tzedakah, not the permissibility of the **asking** for it.

Comment: Actually, the other question asks specifically about both collecting and giving. ("Many times, people collect money during davening, including during birchos krias shema, and the custom is to give during that time. Is This mutar?") However, it's about _bircos k'rias "
Sh'ma"_ specifically, and this is about "all times of davening".

Comment: @msh210 I read it differently
"and the custom is to **give** during that time. Is This mutar?" and "Where does **giving** tzedakah stand?". Furthermore in the comment "my question was not about the sensitivity of the tzedaka collectors."

Comment: Fair enough, yeah.